# row of floating divs on fluid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a row of divs that are set to float left. it's a fixed layout so it all fits nice and properly...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6IF3.gif

I'm in the process of converting this layout to a fluid one (for mobile devices) and i've ran into an annoying issue. If the window is resized it leaves unwanted blank space on the right side...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwj6r.gif

Is there a way to resize those floating divs so that they fill up all the width? Will i need jquery or just CSS?

Comment: You can give the blocks percentage based widths, so they expand and contract as you want. You can then use media queries to set different break-points where you see more or less blocks on a line (by giving them different percentage widths). Be aware that you probably will also want to use percentage based `padding` and `margin` values as well.

Comment: Is there a javascript solution that would adjust the width of the floating divs depending on the browsers width?

Comment: You can bind to the `window.resize` event and calculate the width/padding of each cell based on their container's size. Here's a demo of using only CSS to create a responsive design: http://jsfiddle.net/p2pkK/